# How to add target line in google column chart?

Tags: google-visualization

How to add the target line in google column chart like this.

[image: google column chart]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you'd like to combine the columnchart and linechart, use ComboChart. Documentation and examples are here : 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart

basically, have the data point for the line chart as one of the columns in the DataTable and specify this column to be the "series" = "line", whereas the other columns are visualized in a ColumnChart.

Comment: A stepped area for the target series would be closer to that. Just make sure to specify 0% opacity for the area fill and you'll probably want to set "connectSteps" to false so each year has it's own line above it.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this technique using a ComboChart worked nicely in my case where we need 3 different target lines. The legend associates a colour with each line and its label.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [Stepped Area](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/steppedareachart) series to achieve this. It's a little awkward but works well.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Ecuador', 'Madagascar', 'Papua New Guinea', 'Rwanda', ''],
    ['2004/05',  165,      938,         522,             998,           450,      250],
    ['2005/06',  135,      1120,        599,             1268,          288,      250],
    ['2006/07',  157,      1167,        587,             807,           397,      250],
    ['2007/08',  139,      1110,        615,             968,           215,      250],
    ['2008/09',  136,      691,         629,             1026,          366,      250]
]);

var options = {
    seriesType: "line",
    series: {5: {
      type: "steppedArea", 
      color: '#FF0000', 
      visibleInLegend: false, 
      areaOpacity: 0}
    }
};

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));    
chart.draw(data, options);
```

[image: Horizontal target line on Google Chart]

### Example

[Stepped Area Google Chart Example](https://jsfiddle.net/8p6z4631/2/)

Answer (score 2):

To make the steppedArea @Ryan suggested above a litte bit less awkward, you can setup a second (right) axis and set the base line to the value you want for the target line. The second axis will be setup for the seppedArea data. This avoids the uggly outline effect when you hover the pointer over the chart and under the line. Do something like this in the options:

```
var options = {
    seriesType: "line",
    series: {5: {
        type: "steppedArea", 
        color: '#FF0000', 
        visibleInLegend: false, 
        areaOpacity: 0,
        targetAxisIndex: 1 } //tell the series values to be shown in axe 1 bellow
    },
    vAxes: [  //each object in this array refers to one axe setup
        {},  //axe 0 without any special configurations
        {
            ticks: [250], //use this if you want to show the target value
            baseline: 250 //this shifts the base line to 250
        }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the ugly outline, just use:  `enableInteractivity: false`