# Multiple target lines in Google Visualization

Tags: google-visualization, data-visualization

I'm using Google Visualization to display a target vs performance chart. The chart is split into a few months, and within each month, I have several departments, each with their own targets. The actual performance will be displayed using bar (column) charts, while I'm intending to have the targets displayed as a line. For now, I've chosen to use a stepped area chart with 0 opacity and disconnected lines for the targets, as recommended by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178030/how-to-add-target-line-in-google-column-chart#comment19184389_13736287) comment.

The issue now is that the stepped area chart displays across the entire category, but I need it to display only across a single column. Currently what I have is (copy and paste the code in the Google Code Playground to see the results):

```js
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Ecuador', 'Madagascar', 'Papua New Guinea', 'Rwanda', 'Average'],
    ['2004/05',  165,      938,         522,             998,           450,      614.6],
    ['2005/06',  135,      1120,        599,             1268,          288,      682],
    ['2006/07',  157,      1167,        587,             807,           397,      623],
    ['2007/08',  139,      1110,        615,             968,           215,      609.4],
    ['2008/09',  136,      691,         629,             1026,          366,      569.6]
 ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  var ac = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  ac.draw(data, {
    title : 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    vAxis: {title: "Cups"},
    hAxis: {title: "Month"},
    seriesType: "bars",
    connectSteps: false, 
    series: {3: {type: "steppedArea", areaOpacity: 0}}
  });
}
```

​
I'm also open to other possible ideas of how to display a target vs performance chart, so other solutions that can also create such a chart would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but what you want to do isn't possible in the Visualization API.  There may be a way to hack something together to get the effect you want, I'll have to think about it and see what I come up with.

Comment: I see. I've been looking at multiple charting libraries and it seems to be incredibly difficult to find a charting library that's capable of creating performance vs target charts (in any form). And I am reluctant to use a full drawing library (like d3js) as it seems like severe overkill for something that's supposed to be simple. Like I said, all I really need is a performance vs target chart, and any way to achieve that would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I had something that I was sure was going to work, but it fails due to a quirk in the way the charts create space for columns in a chart with a numeric x-axis (they calculate the smallest difference between any two points in any series and use that as the maximum width for all column groups, even when the columns are not part of the series with the smallest gap).  You can see the results of what I did so far here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/M7YTG/1/ if that helps.

Comment: Oh, just thought of something!  You can use the "interval" column role to add error bars to values, but it could also serve as your target.  How does this look to you?  http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/M7YTG/2/

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I need! Only a couple of issues:

1) When I change the x-axis to a grouped axis, like month, the bars seem kinda short. A way to define their length would be good.
2) Also, is there a way to change the colour of the interval bars? The default colours are a little close to the original bar colours, which makes them kinda hard to see.

Comment: There's no way to adjust the width of the line used in the interval or change its color.  You could try to use a Date-based axis and format it to display months, which would give you the wider lines used with continuous-axis charts.

Comment: Oh well, I've been hitting so many brick walls since I started trying to find something that can even come close to this. The date axis does help with the length, and I guess the colours will have to do. Thanks so much for all your help. If you'll post your solution as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "interval" column role to add a small horizontal line in line with the column:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Month');
data.addColumn('number', 'Y1');
data.addColumn({type: 'number', label: 'Y1 Target', role: 'interval'});
data.addColumn('number', 'Y2');
data.addColumn({type: 'number', label: 'Y1 Target', role: 'interval'});
data.addRows([
    ['Jan', 5, 7, 4, 10],
    ['Feb', 3, 4, 8, 6],
    ['Mar', 6, 3, 6, 8],
    ['Apr', 2, 5, 3, 6]
]);
```

see example at http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/M7YTG/2/

Comment: Herioc. "The width of the horizontal bars corresponding to the first and last columns is controlled with intervals.barWidth, and the width of the horizontal bars corresponding to the inner columns is controlled with intervals.shortBarWidth." - so - with a little styling increasing width one can achieve lines also.
With PointSize set to 0 and passing the first value over first and last can elide the vertical stripe