# Advanced customization of google charts generated from a spreadsheet

Tags: google-visualization

I have my beautiful google bar chart that I generated just clicking in "insert chart" from google spreadsheet.
how can I modify it in an advanced way like writing code?
I have to insert a horizontal line in the bar chart that represent the productivity limit.
if I could do that without writing code would be better, but even writing code, I'd like to edit the chart generated by google spreadsheet, not start from scratches.
Tnx!

Comment: The options for editing a chart created from the spreadsheets are rather limited.  If you don't mind writing some javascript, you can fetch data from your spreadsheet using a `Query` and customize the chart however you need.  See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets) for details, and some examples ([1](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#data_source_request), [2](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#using_the_query_language)) on the Visualization Playground.

Comment: Should I do 2 differnt data requests if I need to get part of the data from a sheet and another part forma another sheet?

Comment: I believe that you have to make multiple queries if you are pulling data from different sheets.

Comment: Now I have my beautiful column chart, but I can't find in the Configuration Options how to set the horizontal line that i need.
Should this line be an axis or another kinf of line?

Can you help me :D

TNX

Comment: Ask a new question with a description of what you would like to achieve, what you have already tried, and the code you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem in this way.

I took the example forum [google](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets) and i add the link that I got sharing my spreadsheet adding in the end of the link:

```
&sheet=PivotGiorni&range=A2:B
```

This set the sheet and the range.

Then the chart just work.

for adding the line I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178030/how-to-add-target-line-in-google-column-chart).

Thanks to you all! :D