# How to format a "target" line in a google combo chart to go across the whole chart area

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a simple google combo chart like this

https://jsfiddle.net/bxd6ngd1/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="chart_div"></div>

google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'target'],
    ['2013', 1000, 1100],
    ['2014', 1170, 1100],
    ['2015', 660, 1100]
  ]);

  var options = {

      seriesType: 'bars',
      series: {1: {type: 'line'}}
    };

  var chart = new     google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);


}
```

Can I format the red "target" line to go across the whole chart from right to left and NOT start in the middle of the first column and end in the middle of the last one?

Comment: Use a stepped area? http://stackoverflow.com/a/31738554

Comment: Thank you @Ryan . It's so simple it's brilliant :) oh, and yes.. I DO feel stupid for not finding the post you showed me :) thanks man